# Entity Framework and Windows Form DataGrid view - table join and bind to user controls

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagrid

I have 3 Tables as follows:

```
Main Table = (ID, name)
Parameters Table = (ParameterID, Parameter Value, MainID)
Parameters Names Table = (ParameterID, ParameterName)

Main Table --> Details Parameters Table is a one to many relationship
Parameters Table to Parameters Names is a one to one relationship
```

I want to **databind** and display ALL parameters Name in column one of the datagridview and parameter values in column 2 for a particular main ID.

My current solution is :

LINQ query that does a left outer join from parameter names table to parameters table which gives me the Datagrid view (all parameter names, parameter values).

Now the issue is, this is not really bound to Entity Framework as it is just a projection, I know I can loop through the datagrid entries and achieve what i want,

Is there a better approach to solve this i.e. can we do a join and also bind to controls directly in a windows form datagrid? This is so the user form can directly allow a user to update/delete/insert items from a joined result.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could share a [mcve]

Comment: I don't think what are you asking can be achieved automatically. The only way to get automatic update/delete/add is to bind data grid view to Parameters table, but then it won't show all parameters.

Comment: Yes @IvanStoev, that is what i thought - I just wanted to see if there are any alternate methods. Is using the datagrid even the best approach here? I am quite new to C#.

Comment: DataGridView is ok. But in order to perform what you need, you have to create a `ViewModel` class (what I guess you are doing with the query), and finally apply changes by hand back to the entity framework context. Pretty similar to how MVC controllers and views work.